# How to output the cat_Id of a category sent by an api on clicking that category

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching the list of categories from an api, I want to output the categoryId(id) associated with that category on click of that category. The json output of the api has id and name. This is the code I am using:

```
const fetchData = () => {
    const categoryApi = "//apilink";
       
    const getCategory = axios.get(categoryApi);
    
    axios.all([getCategory, getStore]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allCategory = allData[0].data.brand_categories;
        
        setCategory(allCategory);
        
      })
    )
  }


useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

Printing the categories this way

```
<div className="sidebar">
          <p style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 600, marginTop: "0" }}>categories</p>
          {
            category.map((item) => (
              <div>
                {item.name}

              </div>

            ))
          }

        </div>

enter code here
```

Comment: Did you get the relevant data from the API call? if you did not check yet try to console log it

Comment: I got the correct data I just want to write an onClick function which will output the id as an alert, My json has both category id and name

Comment: someone suggested me this, but I don't know how to write the on click function

1.Use HTML data attributes to store the category id in the div 
2. write a onClick function on the div 
3. Get the data attribute from the onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you want to add onClick event to show the id on alert, if I got you right, it's simple if you got the `id` inside the `item` object (from `category` array).

You can add the onClick attribute in the `<div>` element, like so:

```
        category.map((item) => (
          <div onClick={() => alert(item.id)>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))`
```

You can either call for a function that will trigger onClick and will execute the code there if you want to alert or whatever you need else. 
Hope you got the point, let me know if you need extra explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193978/i-have-to-show-stores-listed-on-my-platform-depending-upon-the-category-selected